# toggle checkbox under ::affter

Tags: jquery

How will I find the toggle button value "hide" or "show" ?

Go to URL : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castle the text next to Content is hide or show toggle How to find text "Show" or "Hide" Inspect element for the toggle code is mentioned below
Steps:

1. Go to URL : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castle
2. the text next to Content table is hide or show toggle
3. How to find text "Show" or "Hide"
4. Inspect element for the toggle code is mentioned above

```
<div id="toc" class="toc" role="navigation" aria-labelledby="mw-toc-heading">
<input type="checkbox" role="button" id="toctogglecheckbox" class="toctogglecheckbox" style="display:none">
<div class="toctitle" lang="en" dir="ltr">
   <h2 id="mw-toc-heading">Contents</h2>
   <span class="toctogglespan">
   ::before
   <label class="toctogglelabel" for="toctogglecheckbox">
   ::after
   </label>
   </span>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"find text"_? The text is set via [CSS content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content)

Comment: Thanks for reply. In my script  need to check When it shows Hide , the content is hidden. Where will in the html I find the text 'hide' ?  Also, I am new to ::after and ::before. Can you please help me understand what does ::after and ::before do ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting and manipulating CSS pseudo-elements such as ::before and ::after using javascript (or jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need something like this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#togglecontent').on('click', function(){
        $("#contents").toggle('hide');
        $(this).text(function(i, text){
          return text === "hide" ? "show" : "hide";
      })      
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
   <label>Contents</label>
   [<a href="#" id="togglecontent">hide</a>]
</div>
<div id="contents">
<ul>
<li class="toclevel-1 tocsection-1"><a href="#Definition"><span class="tocnumber">1</span> <span class="toctext">Definition</span></a>
<ul>
<li class="toclevel-2 tocsection-2"><a href="#Etymology"><span class="tocnumber">1.1</span> <span class="toctext">Etymology</span></a></li>
<li class="toclevel-2 tocsection-3"><a href="#Defining_characteristics"><span class="tocnumber">1.2</span> <span class="toctext">Defining characteristics</span></a></li>
<li class="toclevel-2 tocsection-4"><a href="#Terminology"><span class="tocnumber">1.3</span> <span class="toctext">Terminology</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="toclevel-1 tocsection-5"><a href="#Common_features"><span class="tocnumber">2</span> <span class="toctext">Common features</span></a>
<ul>
<li class="toclevel-2 tocsection-6"><a href="#Motte"><span class="tocnumber">2.1</span> <span class="toctext">Motte</span></a></li>
<li class="toclevel-2 tocsection-7"><a href="#Bailey_and_enceinte"><span class="tocnumber">2.2</span> <span class="toctext">Bailey and enceinte</span></a></li>
<li class="toclevel-2 tocsection-8"><a href="#Keep"><span class="tocnumber">2.3</span> <span class="toctext">Keep</span></a></li>
<li class="toclevel-2 tocsection-9"><a href="#Curtain_wall"><span class="tocnumber">2.4</span> <span class="toctext">Curtain wall</span></a></li>
<li class="toclevel-2 tocsection-10"><a href="#Gatehouse"><span class="tocnumber">2.5</span> <span class="toctext">Gatehouse</span></a></li>
<li class="toclevel-2 tocsection-11"><a href="#Moat"><span class="tocnumber">2.6</span> <span class="toctext">Moat</span></a></li>
<li class="toclevel-2 tocsection-12"><a href="#Battlements"><span class="tocnumber">2.7</span> <span class="toctext">Battlements</span></a></li>
<li class="toclevel-2 tocsection-13"><a href="#Arrowslits"><span class="tocnumber">2.8</span> <span class="toctext">Arrowslits</span></a></li>
<li class="toclevel-2 tocsection-14"><a href="#Postern"><span class="tocnumber">2.9</span> <span class="toctext">Postern</span></a></li>
<li class="toclevel-2 tocsection-15"><a href="#Great_hall"><span class="tocnumber">2.10</span> <span class="toctext">Great hall</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="toclevel-1 tocsection-16"><a href="#History"><span class="tocnumber">3</span> <span class="toctext">History</span></a>
<ul>
<li class="toclevel-2 tocsection-17"><a href="#Antecedents"><span class="tocnumber">3.1</span> <span class="toctext">Antecedents</span></a></li>
<li class="toclevel-2 tocsection-18"><a href="#Origins_(9th_and_10th_centuries)"><span class="tocnumber">3.2</span> <span class="toctext">Origins (9th and 10th centuries)</span></a></li>
<li class="toclevel-2 tocsection-19"><a href="#11th_century"><span class="tocnumber">3.3</span> <span class="toctext">11th century</span></a></li>
<li class="toclevel-2 tocsection-20"><a href="#Innovation_and_scientific_design_(12th_century)"><span class="tocnumber">3.4</span> <span class="toctext">Innovation and scientific design (12th century)</span></a></li>
<li class="toclevel-2 tocsection-21"><a href="#13th_to_15th_centuries"><span class="tocnumber">3.5</span> <span class="toctext">13th to 15th centuries</span></a></li>
<li class="toclevel-2 tocsection-22"><a href="#Advent_of_gunpowder"><span class="tocnumber">3.6</span> <span class="toctext">Advent of gunpowder</span></a></li>
<li class="toclevel-2 tocsection-23"><a href="#Bastions_and_star_forts_(16th_century)"><span class="tocnumber">3.7</span> <span class="toctext">Bastions and star forts (16th century)</span></a></li>
<li class="toclevel-2 tocsection-24"><a href="#Later_use_and_revival_castles"><span class="tocnumber">3.8</span> <span class="toctext">Later use and revival castles</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="toclevel-1 tocsection-25"><a href="#Construction"><span class="tocnumber">4</span> <span class="toctext">Construction</span></a></li>
<li class="toclevel-1 tocsection-26"><a href="#Social_centre"><span class="tocnumber">5</span> <span class="toctext">Social centre</span></a></li>
<li class="toclevel-1 tocsection-27"><a href="#Locations_and_landscapes"><span class="tocnumber">6</span> <span class="toctext">Locations and landscapes</span></a></li>
<li class="toclevel-1 tocsection-28"><a href="#Warfare"><span class="tocnumber">7</span> <span class="toctext">Warfare</span></a></li>
<li class="toclevel-1 tocsection-29"><a href="#See_also"><span class="tocnumber">8</span> <span class="toctext">See also</span></a></li>
<li class="toclevel-1 tocsection-30"><a href="#References"><span class="tocnumber">9</span> <span class="toctext">References</span></a>
<ul>
<li class="toclevel-2 tocsection-31"><a href="#Notes"><span class="tocnumber">9.1</span> <span class="toctext">Notes</span></a></li>
<li class="toclevel-2 tocsection-32"><a href="#Bibliography"><span class="tocnumber">9.2</span> <span class="toctext">Bibliography</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="toclevel-1 tocsection-33"><a href="#Further_reading"><span class="tocnumber">10</span> <span class="toctext">Further reading</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Demo jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/kdhtms3b/2/